# How to use the pyjnius read and write arguments for Bluetooth getInputStream and getOutputStream?

Tags: java, android, python-3.x, bluetooth, pyjnius

I have been fumbling with getting data from a bluetooth RS232 converter using the python for android jnius library.  I had thought that it would be as simple as the PySerial library, but as I am still new to java the implementation is quite different.  
I created the bluetooth connection quite easily, but as soon as I try to read or write data I get a `jnius.jnius.JavaException` that `No methods matching your arguments,` and that the methods available for `read` are:  `'()I', '([B)I', '([BII)I'` and for `write` are `'(I)V', '([B)V', '([BII)V'`.  I tried finding this in the developer android docs as well as DuckDuckGoing it but with no clarity. 
 I also tried the `BufferedReader` example ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719898/how-to-convert-android-bluetooth-socket-inputstream-to-python-string-in-kivy)) using the `readLine()` method, but I am constantly getting an error:  `JavaException:  JVM exception occurred: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.io.InputStream.read(byte[], int, int)' on a null object reference`.

Can someone please point me to the documentation to understand the above read and write arguments? 
Also, please help me to understand why the `read, readLine() and write` objects does not return any data?

Java libraries I call:

```
BluetoothAdapter = autoclass('android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter')
BluetoothDevice = autoclass('android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice')
BluetoothSocket = autoclass('android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket')
InputStreamReader = autoclass('java.io.InputStreamReader')
BufferedReader = autoclass('java.io.BufferedReader')
UUID = autoclass('java.util.UUID')
System = autoclass('java.lang.System')
```

Connecting code (got this from Github and above link):

```
    def get_socket_stream(self, name):
        paired_devices = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBondedDevices().toArray()
        self.rfsocket == None
        for device in paired_devices:
            if device.getName() == name:
                if device.bluetoothEnabled:
                    if not device.connected:
                        self.rfsocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                            UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"))
                        self.reader = InputStreamReader(self.rfsocket.getInputStream(), 'LATIN-1')
                        recv_stream = BufferedReader(self.reader)
                        send_stream = self.rfsocket.getOutputStream()
                        break
        print(self.rfsocket.getRemoteDevice().getName())
        if self.rfsocket.port <= 0:
            self.rfsocket = device.createRfcommSocket(1)
            if not self.rfsocket.connected:
                print('port two: ',self.rfsocket.port)
                self.rfsocket.connect()
```

Read and write code (source: same as above link):

```
    def GetBSerial(self):
        self.messager('Trying Serial')
        self.recv_stream, self.send_stream = self.get_socket_stream(devicename)
        if  not self.rfsocket.connected and self.recv_stream == None:
            print("Get paired device failed")
        else:
            print('Initiating trigger')
            self.weight_ticker()
    def GetInput(self):
        self.send_stream.write("Hallo\r\n")
        self.send_stream.flush
        if self.rfsocket.connected and self.recv_stream != None:
            if self.weigh_tme > 0:
                while self.recv_stream.ready != None:
                    try:
                        self.scale_output = self.recv_stream.readLine()
                    except jnius.jnius.JavaException as e:
                        print("JavaException: ", e, self.rfsocket.connected)
                    except ValueError as e:
                        print("Misc error: ", e)

                    try:
                        self.show_input(self.scale_output)
                    except ValueError:
                        pass
```

#### Update:

So I finally got the Input using the `readLine()` method to not return an error and also return the string.  I cleaned things up a bit, but the code does not differ much.  Main thing though is I checked whether the `device != None` and `if rfsocket.connected:` before creating getInputStream within my eventloop, so as not to re-create the socket object.  Have to test more to see where was the main problem.  Still do not no what the arguments are of the `read` and `write` method.  The `readLine()` method returns the string intermitantly or not at all and my eventloop seems to not work with the `readLine()` method.

#### Update on update:

The event loop works again.  My bad, I did not call the trigger object correctly.  The `readLine()` method has a strange pattern in that on the first read it gives me `JavaException:  JVM exception occurred: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.io.InputStream.available()' on a null object reference`, subsequent reads gives me pieces of the expected string or an empty string.  I had similar string bits and pieces returned when I received the data via a hardline using PySerial.  The solution was resetting the input buffer.  Is there something similar in the above java libraries?

## Finally cracked the exceptions:

Yes, this is exciting!  After many hours I had noticed that I could not get the Input anymore only exceptions.  I tried the `BufferedInputStream` library and got the same result, there was no more intermittant read.  Why?  So I re-Apk'd the `main` file of last night and boom intermittant Input read once again. 
 
The reason was if I create the java objects when the `rfsocket` Bluetooth object is not connected to the specified port, `Null` objects was initialised on a different port which for some reason was not seen by the `if` blocks `self.recv_stream is not None` and `self.recv_stream != None`.  Probably because they are not `Null` objects but `Null` for the subsequent port 1 socket connection I specified.
The `readline()` work as is in my example, the `read()` takes three arguments `bytes(), int offset, int len(bytes()` which is not clear from the `jnius.jnius.exception` hieroglyphics' message.  Still figuring out the `write` method.  One thing that you can specify in the `BufferedReader` method is a 2nd argument for the chunk size you want to read or in java speak `defaultCharBufferSize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am posting  my answers as I have solved them all.
To connect to bluetooth I built on the [GitHub example](https://gist.github.com/cuibonobo/10439718) by following the suggestions on the [android developers site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth).  I had to set my own socket explicitly before creating the `getOutputStream` and `getInputStream` java objects otherwise the ports of the connection and objects will not be the same.  You only need to call the `GetBSerial()` to connect

```
    def get_socket_stream(self, name):
        defaultCharBufferSize = 8192
        try:
            blueAdapt = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
            if self.rfsocket is not None:
                if self.rfsocket.connected:
                    reader = InputStreamReader(self.rfsocket.getInputStream(), getEncode)
                    recv_stream = BufferedReader(reader)
                    send_stream = self.rfsocket.getOutputStream()
                else:
                    self.rfsocket = self.device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(getUuid))
                    if self.get_port_connect():
                        reader = InputStreamReader(self.rfsocket.getInputStream(), getEncode)
                        recv_stream = BufferedReader(reader, defaultCharBufferSize)
                        send_stream = self.rfsocket.getOutputStream()
            else:
                if blueAdapt is not None:
                    if blueAdapt.isEnabled():
                        paired_devices = blueAdapt.getBondedDevices().toArray()
                        self.rfsocket = None
                        for self.device in paired_devices:
                            if self.device.getName() == name:
                                if self.device.bluetoothEnabled:
                                    self.rfsocket = self.device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                                        UUID.fromString(getUuid))
                                    if self.rfsocket is not None:
                                        if self.get_port_connect(): #connect and set the port before creating java objects
                                            reader = InputStreamReader(self.rfsocket.getInputStream(), getEncode)
                                            recv_stream = BufferedReader(reader, defaultCharBufferSize)
                                            send_stream = self.rfsocket.getOutputStream()
                                            break
                    else:
                        self.ids.bluet_info.text = '[b]Bluetooth not enabled[/b]'
            if recv_stream is not None and send_stream is not None:
                return recv_stream, send_stream
            else:
                return False, False
        except UnboundLocalError as e:
            return False, False
        except TypeError as e:
            return False, False
    def get_port_connect(self):
        try:
            if self.rfsocket.port <= 0:
                self.rfsocket = self.device.createRfcommSocket(1) #set the port explicitly
                if not self.rfsocket.connected:
                    self.rfsocket.connect()
            else:
                if not self.rfsocket.connected:
                    self.rfsocket.connect()
            if self.rfsocket.connected:
                self.ids.bluet_info.text = '[b]Connected[/b]'
            return True
        except jnius.jnius.JavaException as e:
            self.ids.bluet_info.text = '[b]Cannot connect to socket[/b]'
    def GetBSerial(self):
        try:
            getDevname = self.the.config.get('bluetoothsettings', 'stringbluetdevname')
            self.recv_stream, self.send_stream = self.get_socket_stream(getDevname)
        except jnius.jnius.JavaException as e:
            self.ids.bluet_info.text = '[b]Not Connected[/b]'
```

I used the `readLine()` method, but to use the `read()` method, there are two ways to  build a string.  Either externally (I only tried this one) or in an Array.
Import:

```
CharBuilder = autoclass('java.lang.Character')
```

Externally:

```
if self.recv_stream.ready() != None:
    r = self.recv_stream.read()
    theChar = CharBuilder.toChars(r) #gives a tuple of which the first element is a character
    self.read += theChar[0]
```

You have to play around with building your string to know where the string must start.
The first thing about the `write()` method is it takes a bytes object.  So you build a `bytearray()` and use it as an argument.  Example using ESC/POS printer initialise command and a string:

```
i = [27,64] #ASCII escape integer and at sign integer
pre = bytearray(i)
cmd = 'Hello You\n'.encode('UTF-8')
#extend bytearray
pre.extend(cmd)
self.send_stream.write(pre)
self.send_stream.flush()
```

Could not figure out how to create a bytearray integer and string in one go, yet.

Comment: great work on what you did above. I just had a problem with `createRfcommSocket()`, It give `JVM exception occurred: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1` 
How were you able to go around that? Needed a little insight.

Comment: I created the `get_port_connect(self)` function as shown in my example.  It checks if the port is less than equal to 0.  If `true` it sets the port explicitly to 1.  This is done before creating the java `stream` objects.  Have you tried it?

Comment: thanks for the response. I think I did try that, but now I found out that since I am working with BLE and I think I have to use the java GATT interfaces for Android. I am now stuck with an error at `connectGatt()` after following this link http://tableauxmaths.fr/spip/spip.php?article156

Comment: I have not yet used BLE or the GATT interface, only Bluetooth Classic.  Sorry cannot give you more info.  The low energy stuff is planned for 2022 season along with a move towards C (I hope) and away from Java.

Comment: Alright! Thank you @Hmerman6006 . Hoping for the best.